# Writing and reading from file to struct or the reverse in c

Tags: c, file-io, linked-list

Well... I am new in c.
I have a problem. I have 2 struct. 1 is node list which is linked list and 1 is array of struct which linked to node. This is how I declare it.

```
    typedef struct mhs mhs;
    typedef struct kelas kelas;

struct mhs
{
    char nama[31];
    char nim[16];
    int angkatan;
    float ipk;
};

struct kelas
{
    char kls[13];
    int jml;
    mhs siswa[40];
    kelas *next;
};
```

kelas=node and mhs=array of struct
I wanna to make a file based on node. So if I have 3 node then I will write 3 different file and inside it contain mhs and I also wanna to make node->kls as namefile. Is that possible? If yes how I can do it? Thanks for your advance.

Comment: What are you having trouble with - iterating over a linked list?  Writing to a file in C?

Comment: Writing to a file maybe
I never implement it for now. What method should I use? I can't get node->kls to become my namefile and writing to differnet files

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
#include <stdio.h>


int printNodesToFile(kelas* node) {
    char filename[100] = {0};

    int idx;
    for(idx = 1; node = node->next, idx++; node != NULL) {
        snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "kelas.%d.txt", idx);
        FILE* outFile = fopen(filename, "w");
        if(outFile == NULL) return 1;
        //do stuff
        fclose(outFile);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How to write my mhs to that file?
I am trying to do this 
for(int i=0;i<itr->jml;i++)
                fprintf("%d. %s; %s; %d; %.2f\n",i+1,itr->siswa[i].nama,itr->siswa[i].nim,itr->siswa[i].angkatan,itr->siswa[i].ipk);
but it can't compile

Comment: It says "arg 1 is not struct *". Something like that.

Comment: I am trying to do this
fprintf(outFile,"%d. %s; %s; %d; %.2f\n",i+1,itr->siswa[i].nama,itr->siswa[i].nim,itr->siswa[i].angkatan,itr->siswa[i].ipk)
Is this correct?
But why I open it, it can't be read? Is that saved with binary data?

Comment: In what sense can't you read it if you open it?  Do you see junk characters?

Comment: For starters your format string is wrong.  Read up on how printf works.

Comment: @djechlin, The OP wanted `node->kls` to store the filename. So your `fopen()` should be `fopen(node->kls, "w")`.